# Text File Comparision

Tags: java

I am implementing tool for comparison of two text file in java.
Text file contain only numeric, alphanumeric and keyboard symbol. 
Compare one file with other and find spelling, punctuation or missing text error.

Example:

```
Original word: Her
 Error Word: hor   
It is spelling error

Original word: Miss
 Error Word: miss 
It is Punctuation error
```

no need to used dictionary because for spelling also it compare from original file. If in original file word is her and in second file that word is hor than it generate spelling error but problem is than classification of spelling, punctuation or missing text not done well

If there is available any function or tool which will solve my problem than please suggest me.

Comment: Java it self does not offer any Spell checking functionality, it will just split up the String for you. So if you want to do spelling checking you either have to do it yourself or use an API like  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/?

Comment: I dont think he is looking for a spell checking api. he wants to compare words in two different files and on that basis do spellcheck.

A correct word(original word) could be "heree" and in other file could be "here" (which by dictionary is right) but in comparison to original word is wrong.

Comment: or something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/Grep.java

Comment: @Mayur, can you verify what you exactly want? to use a dictionary as "dngfng" mentioned or you are trying to implement what i mentioed in my comment above? Thanks

Comment: I want to generate report from which show spelling, missing text and punctuation error in second file.
Compare that file with my original file

Comment: Yes, that is my point. missing text and punctuation you will get by comparing with other file.  now for spellcheck. you want to use dictionary or the correct spelling would also be checked from the original file ?

Comment: I really not want to check spelling is right or wrong, but to distribute error, if word not matches than which error is it? spelling, punctuation or missing text error.

Comment: Ohkkie.. Got you
can you update your question with this update. as most of the people are thinking that you want to do spell check and giving you links to use dictionary API`s

Comment: no need to used dictionary because for spelling also it compare from original file.  If in original file word is her and in second file that word is hor than it generate spelling error but problem is than classification of spelling, punctuation or missing text not done well

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a dictionary [Trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). That is the only way for spell correction possible with predictable results.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment under the original post, I'll ask for clarification here.

Is the problem "How to tell if a word is missing"?  For example, if you have the lines:

"My name is Roy and here is a bunch of other text"

"My name Roy and here is a bunch of other text"

Because the second line is missing the word "is", the program reports a bunch of spelling errors instead of a missing word error?

Comment: if first is original line than it gives missing test:”is” error 
but problem is that it generate bunch of spelling error after not matching ‘is’ in  first line and  ‘roy’ in second line.

Comment: @mayur Rank, brother if that is the problem then, whenever a missing word is encountered, leave the second line pointer there itself and traverse the first line pointer to next word.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem.  Alas, I have no easy answer for you, but a quick Google search reveals that this seems to be a common problem.  Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff under "algorithm" describes the problem.  If you Google "diff java" (without quotes), you'll find plenty of links talking about the problem, and various solutions.  Hopefully they'll make sense to you.  Good luck!